# How to increase the size of the text inside the red circle of the cor plot?

Tags: ggplot2, visualization, correlation, psych

How to increase the size of the text inside the red circle of the cor plot? [image: click here]

Used code:

```
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
pairs.panels(data, 
             method = "pearson", 
             hist.col = "#00AFBB",
             density = TRUE,  
             ellipses = TRUE,
             pch = 21,
             cex = 1.5,
             cex.axis = 1.8,
             lwd = 2,
             rug = TRUE,
             stars = TRUE
)
```

Comment: I suspect that pairs.panels comes from a package which you have neither named nor provided a library call to load. Also no data. Voting to close as needing debugging details.

Comment: so can you give an alternate option (code as per my data) for example in ggplot? I am new to R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer and i.e. to add the argument `cex.labels = 2.5,`

the final code is

```
library(psych)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
pairs.panels(data, 
             method = "pearson", 
             hist.col = "#00AFBB",
             density = TRUE,  
             ellipses = TRUE,
             pch = 21,
             cex = 1.5,
             cex.axis = 1.8,
             cex.labels = 2.5,
             lwd = 2,
             rug = TRUE,
             stars = TRUE
)
```